# asp.net repeater in update panel databind outside page_load

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

I have repeater in updatePanel asp.net. It works fine when I run databind() in Page_load method. But when databind() is called by some event outside Page_load, repeater cleared. Databind() does not work in this case! What can be reason for this? 
this is code ...

this works:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ........      
    populateCalendar(Int32.Parse(DDL_YearsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_MonthsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_EmployeesList.SelectedValue));

}

private void populateCalendar(int year, int month, int idEmploee)
{
.......     
    monthShower.DataSource = listWeeks;
    monthShower.DataBind();
}
protected void DDL_EmployeesList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //populateCalendar(Int32.Parse(DDL_YearsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_MonthsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_EmployeesList.SelectedValue));
}
```

this does not work, when DDL_EmployeesList_SelectedIndexChanged fired:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ........      
   // populateCalendar(Int32.Parse(DDL_YearsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_MonthsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_EmployeesList.SelectedValue));

}

private void populateCalendar(int year, int month, int idEmploee)
{
.......     
    monthShower.DataSource = listWeeks;
    monthShower.DataBind();
}

protected void DDL_EmployeesList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    populateCalendar(Int32.Parse(DDL_YearsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_MonthsList.SelectedValue), Int32.Parse(DDL_EmployeesList.SelectedValue));
}
```

`<asp:Repeater id ="monthShower" runat ="server"> <ItemTemplate> <custom:DayID="Day1" runat ="server" TblDay =<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Monday") %>></custom:Day> </ItemTemplate> </asp:Repeater>`

Answer (score 0):

So i did a small test and posted the code

Html:

```
<div id="test">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repTeste" OnItemDataBound="repTeste_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td runat="server" id="tdTeste">

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

C# - I used pop() in my pageLoad just to populate the ddl:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateCalendar(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, 2, 3);
    }
    private void populateCalendar(String year, int month, int idEmploee)
    {
        List<String> lis = new List<String>();
        lis.Add(year);

        repTeste.DataSource = lis;
        repTeste.DataBind();
    }
    private void pop()
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem("1", "1");
        li.Attributes.Add("title", "1");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
        li = new ListItem("2", "2");
        li.Attributes.Add("t2itle", "2");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
        li = new ListItem("3", "3");
        li.Attributes.Add("ti3tle", "3");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
    }

    protected void repTeste_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        String inte = (String)e.Item.DataItem;

        HtmlTableCell td = (HtmlTableCell)e.Item.FindControl("tdTeste");
        td.InnerText = inte;
    }
```

it updates correctly.
Since you didn't post your html and the fact that someone deleted my post, i posted my code here for you, you can use it to compare it or you can post your Html and ill give it a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example is working. My problem is that I use a custom control. That control gets attribute by DataBinder.Eval(). Here is a code    <asp:Repeater id ="monthShower" runat ="server">
<ItemTemplate>
 
 
<custom:Day ID="Day1" runat ="server" TblDay =<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Monday") %>></custom:Day>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater> Probably DataBinder.Eval() does not work outside Page_Load. I wil try use other way to implement required behavior...

Comment: I am not sure but I think 
    
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Monday") %> 

need to be 
     
    "<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Monday") %>"